# react native android project error with firebase

Tags: android, ios, react-native, performance, error-handling

hello i am getting an error in my react native application while integrating the phone authentication.

Error sending OTP: [Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.]

this is the error i have done sha-1 integration to my project and firebase console still not finding any solution i am getting this error when i am calling `await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber("+91347213888");` calling this function on button click and other things like firebase configuration are properly set up in index.js as per documentation   only problem is the error

any questions or code needed i will provide you please tell me

thanku for advance developers in advance  if they solve ...

basic and intermediate developer please dont show your useless comment you dont know answer of this so just dont its for advance developers....